# How to Digitally Sign Email using Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Does anyone know how to digitally sign an email using logic app when sending out an email?
Currently I'm using logic app to send email to my users if there's any change in the system. However, there is a compliance now which requires me to digitally sign any email that is being sent out.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: I think, you can use Docu sign api to be sent along with the mail sent through Logic Apps.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I checked on DocuSign but it seems to be a paid service. Anything existing that we could use or a way around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not supported in Azure Logic App.

You can post your idea on [Azure Logic App User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps).

If your requirement is voted many times, the Microsoft product group will consider adding this feature as appropriate.